# cassandra data modeling with multiple tables

Tags: join, cassandra, structure, datamodel

I have say two tables A1(Health insurance details) and A2(Hospital Visits data)

I understand there are no joins in cassandra. i.e. I cannot query with two tables at a time. What is the work around for this.

Also my data A1 and A2 comes at two different times from two different senders.

A1 is health insurance details and A2 is my hospital visits data. How do I combine these two tables data. There is a common Policy ID in both the tables. As i get these two informations or tables data from two different sources. We are using Cassandra database(Cassandra 3.0) only.

Example

A1( Policy Number, Name, amount paid, etc)...

A2(Hospital visit date, Amount charged, Service received, Policy Number etc)

Answer (score 1):

With cassandra your tables should be query-base designed. If you have 1 table per query the better. I suggest to take a look at: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

Answer (score 0):

In that case we will have to push the data twice or three times into each table for query purpose. Will that be good for us to do that. Also will we have to change the application design to push the data 2 or 3 times. 
Also is there a way where we can push data from one table to other. I know there is export and import method. Is there a Select * from other table option.

I know spark is the solution. I am just wondering if there is solution from cassandra directly.

Thanks

Comment: In that case I would suggest to use batch statements to achieve the consistency on your inserts/updates on your N tables. One thing that could be useful are materialized views, but be wise and careful about it. datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-view‌​s